# How do I insert a list at the front of another list?

Tags: python

```
>>> a = ['foo.py']
>>> k = ['nice', '-n', '10'] 
>>> a.insert(0, k)
>>> a
[['nice', '-n', '10'], 'foo.py']
```

I want to list `k` to be on the same level as `foo.py`, rather than a sublist.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Apply slicing:

```
a[0:0] = k
```

Or do it manually:

```
a = k + a
```

The first approach remain the same for insertion at any place, i.e. `a[n:n] = k`
would insert k at position n, but the second approach would not be the same, that will be

```
a = a[:n] + k + a[n:]
```

Comment: Wow! Let me try to grok that.

Comment: I chose your slicing solution. Thank you.

Comment: Issue with the second approach is you arent mutating the list you are creating a new list, still nice solution because OP didnt specify

Answer (score 14):

instead of:

```
>>> a.insert(0, k)
```

use:

```
>>> k.extend(a)
>>> k
['nice', '-n', '10', 'foo.py']
```

this updates the "k" list "in place" instead of creating a copy.

the list concatenation (k + a) will create a copy.

the slicing option (a[0:0] = k) will also update "in place" but IMHO is harder to read.

Comment: That would append a at the end of k. a would remain the same as before.

Comment: @FlopCoder: it is obvious that he can make a=k, the important point is knowing about in-place and copy concatenation.

Comment: I prefer to mutate `a` in place.

Comment: @Bon Ami: you can choose any form, the important is that you now have knowledge to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 5):

Use list concatenation:

```
a = k + a
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> k + a
['nice', '-n', '10', 'foo.py']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = ['foo.py']
>>> k = ['nice', '-n', '10']
>>> k.extend(a)
>>> print k
['nice', '-n', '10', 'foo.py']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    list1=list(xrange(1,11)) # numbers 1 to 10 in list
    list1[:0]=[0,0,0] # adds triple 0s to front of list
    list1+=[11,12,13] #adds [11,12,13] to the end of list
    print list1
```